# How to recognize default method value setting in Python?

Tags: python, methods, default-value

Consider the following class method definition in Python using default parameter values:

```
class X
..

    def batch(self, param="foobar", limit=2):
    ...
```

Then, a user could call it without arguments, just like

```
x.batch()
```

Result: the parameter values get substituted with default values.

Imagine in such case you would like to tell the user something like:

```
WARNING the batch size has been set to a default value 2.
```

**Question:** is there a way to backtrack either somehow intercept to recognize it (beyond simply moving this initialization and validation logic to a constructor method)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't detect when the default value is being used, but perhaps something like this?

```
import warnings


class X
..

    def batch(self, param="foobar", limit=None):
        if limit == None:
            limit = 2
            warnings.warn(...)

    ...
```